# VWP travelling for 80 days then going to Canada, can I reenter the US and for how long?

Tags: canada, regulations, us-visa-waiver-program

I am travelling in California at the moment under the Visa Waiver Program. I am going to be here until the 9th of December then heading to Michigan for Christmas. I was planning to spend some time in Canada to reset the 90 days but have just heard this isn't possible.

I already have the ticket etc booked, will I have an issue driving back into the US even if I am clearly leaving in a few weeks?

Answer (score 1):

All that matters to the US is that you leave before your 90 days has expired, with the caveat that going to Canada and returning is not considered "leaving".

For example, if you are in the US for 80 days and then Canada for 7 days, then you have a remaining 3 days (80 + 7 + 3 = 90) to depart the US.

Note that you may depart the US by going to Canada and *then* going somewhere outside North America from there (and you can stay in Canada for as long as the Canadian officials will let you without reference to your US entry date).